# Can I fix keyboard on BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

During Android development, there was a need to fix the keyboard on the bottom screen.

example :

[image]

**I hope that the keyboard will not disappear even if you press the back button or display a new dialog in this state.**

Would you give me some advice on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should disable back button using:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        
    }
```

notice that I removed **super.onBackPressed();** it prevents dispatching on backclicked event...

you should also disable canceling button sheet using:

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

hope it helped